# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<django_project_name>' Heroku deployment

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I have seen tens of queries on same topic in past 2 days on web but unfortunately nothing has helped in my case.
I am trying to deploy on Heroku from windows 10. Python manage.py runserver works the job fine on local PC and projects runs.

Here is my project structure

```
austbooks
├── accounting
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── accounting
│   │       ├── css
│   │       └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── account
│   │   └── accounting
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── austbooks
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── manage.py
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── staticfiles
    ├── Accounting
    │   ├── css
    │   └── js
    ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── img
    │   └── js
    ├── debug_toolbar
    │   ├── css
    │   └── js
    └── staticfiles.json
```

I was getting the following error on deployment to heroku

```
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 255, in fetch_command
           app_name = commands[subcommand]
                      ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
       KeyError: 'collectstatic'
       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_20b80918/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_20b80918/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 262, in fetch_command
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1318, in _find_and_load_unlocked
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'austbooks'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`, that enabled me to deploy the app but after that when I opened the app on heroku there was error

`An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail`

Heroku logs gave almost the same error as above, so I reset the DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC.

Here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn austbooks.wsgi
```

Here is my requirements.txt file

```
asgiref==3.7.2
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
certifi==2023.7.22
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==41.0.5
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-database-url==2.1.0
Django==5.0
django-allauth==0.58.2
django-debug-toolbar==4.2.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
idna==3.4
oauthlib==3.2.2
packaging==23.2
psycopg2==2.9.9
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.8.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.5
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.8.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.1.0
whitenoise==6.6.0
```

Collectstatic environment variables:

```
remote:        PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
remote:        PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/pkg-config:/app/.heroku/python/lib/pkg-config:
remote:        DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:        BPLOG_PREFIX=buildpack.python
remote:        PWD=/tmp/build_625825b2
remote:        HOME=/app
remote:        LANG=en_US.UTF-8
remote:        SOURCE_VERSION=47244666b9f674b55aaa9f02a17d31ee4cde1eee
remote:        REQUEST_ID=a7ad9d00-2b14-3b0f-6b3b-4372bc7a2ed4
remote:        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=austbooks.settings
remote:        ENV_DIR=/tmp/d20231206-54-a74wvd
remote:        PYTHONPATH=.
remote:        CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
remote:        BIN_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin
remote:        LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
remote:        SHLVL=1
remote:        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:
remote:        PIP_NO_PYTHON_VERSION_WARNING=1
remote:        BUILDPACK_LOG_FILE=/dev/null
remote:        STACK=heroku-22
remote:        BUILD_DIR=/tmp/build_625825b2
remote:        CACHE_DIR=/tmp/codon/tmp/cache
remote:        PATH=/app/.heroku/python/bin:/app/.heroku/vendor/bin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/vendor/
remote:        EXPORT_PATH=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136/bin/../export
remote:        C_INCLUDE_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/include:/app/.heroku/python/include:
remote:        DYNO=run.2122
remote:        PROFILE_PATH=/tmp/build_625825b2/.profile.d/python.sh
remote:        OLDPWD=/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/0f40890b54a617ec2334fac0439a123c6a0c1136
remote:        _=/usr/bin/env
```

runtime.txt `python-3.12.0`

This is from my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

IS_HEROKU_APP = "DYNO" in os.environ and not "CI" in os.environ

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Use WhiteNoise's runserver implementation instead of the Django default, for dev-prod parity.
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounting',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'austbooks.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'austbooks.wsgi.application'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.ModelBackend',
]


STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounting', 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Static root for Heroku
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

wsgi.py file

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'austbooks.austbooks.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application)
```

I have already tried `web: gunicorn austbooks.wsgi --log-file -` and `web: gunicorn --pythonpath GroomingService GroomingService.wsgi` with `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'austbooks.austbooks.settings')` in wsgi.py but didn't work.

Also I have checked there doesn't seem any spelling or case issues.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the matter solved after struggling for 3 days.
Actually I had django project name as "AustBooks" and had synced it with github. Later I changed the name to "austbooks" changing all letters to small, however surprisingly github did not update the capitals letters and kept it "AustBooks" despite numerous commits.

So changing the project name to something else, committing to github, and then changing back to "austbooks" resolved the issue.